# Best Practice for export List Content to HTML (typo3)?

Tags: list, web-services, export, html, cms

I've got the following problem:

Use Case: I'm creating Events within my intranet with Sharepoint Server 2010. I have a typo3/cms front-end website not connected to sharepoint yet. 
I want to show the events, stored in a SPlist, on my cms/typo3-frontend. I don't want to manually add every new event to the frontend.

I want to export the list contents "as html/xml" to use it within typo3/a front-end web page (I don't really care much about the typo3-part here, could be any CMS / Website) every time the list content changes (or to make it clearer: I delete/add an event).

I searched  around and just found some very expensive third party tools. I'm fairly new to Sharepoint and I hope there is a relatively easy solution for doing this for it's a very common use-case in my opinion.

Would be great to get some help/tips :)

Best Regards, 
Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a web service client to read the list data directly from typo3. Since typo3 is based on PHP you will probably benefit the most from using existing libraries for PHP, such as:

- [thybag / PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API)
- [tangervu / ShareSoap](https://github.com/tangervu/ShareSoap/)
- [RapotOR / Sharepoint-PH](https://github.com/RapotOR/Sharepoint-PHP)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you simply want to read whatever content is in your SharePoint list and display it as content on your typo3 CMS site.  To do this, you could utilize the SharePoint web services to retrieve all the list items from JavaScript (or whatever server-side code you can put into your CMS) and then display them however you want.

There is a CodePlex project that has wrapped the SharePoint 2010 JavaScript calls into a jQuery library: http://spservices.codeplex.com/.  You might start there.

If you have specific questions about how to use the web services, be sure to start some new questions here on SharePoint SE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! spservices are kind of what I'm looking for, too, but eirikb gave a few more scripts and i sadly can't add two answers as right, so... sorry for not giving you the points ;) I will vote this up when reaching 15 reputation, surely.